# When do we need Python Import Statements?

Tags: python, python-import

A piece of code works that I don't see why. It shouldn't work from my understanding. The problem is illustrated easily below:

"Main.py"

```
from x import * #class x is defined
from y import * #class y is defined


xTypeObj = x()
yTypeObj = y()
yTypeObj.func(xTypeObj)
```

"x.py"

```
class x(object):

    def __init__...
        ...
    def functionThatReturnsAString(self):
        return "blah"
```

"y.py"

```
#NO IMPORT STATEMENT NEEDED?? WHY

class y(object):
    def __init__...
        ...
    def func(self, objOfTypeX):
        print(objOfTypeX.functionThatReturnsAString())
```

My question is why do I NOT need to have an import statement in "y.py" of the type

```
from x import functionThatReturnAString()
```

How does it figure out how to call this method?

Comment: You talk about classes and call some methods, but your modules only define functions, not classes and methods... #confusion

Comment: You *really* want to study the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), especially the [section on classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: You passed it in as a parameter.

Comment: @FredLarson: That won't make a difference here.. What do you think will happen yourself?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just an idea. Now that I take a better look at it, I see you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is a dynamically typed language.  Unlike statically typed languages like C++ and Java calls to methods aren't bound until they are actually executed, thus why importing the module were that method is defined is not necessary.  This has several implications:

1. Methods (and data members) can be added to and removed from an instance at runtime, so two instances of class Foo can actually have different methods even though they are of the same type.
2. Methods (and data members) can be added to and removed from a class at runtime, which will impact all current instances as well as new instances.
3. Bases classes can be added and removed to a class at runtime.

Note that this is not an exhaustive list of all of the difference between dynamically typed langauges and statically types languages.

Comment: "Unlike statically typed languages like C++ and Java calls to methods aren't bound until they are actually executed, thus why importing the module were that method is defined is not necessary"  --- exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Python is an object-oriented programming language. In such a language, values are objects, and objects can have methods.

The `functionThatReturnsAString` function is a method on a class, and `objOfTypeX` is an *instance* of that class. Instances of a class carry with them all the methods of it's class.

This is why, for example, `list` objects in python have an `.append()` method:

```
>>> alist = []
>>> alist.append(1)
>>> alist
[1]
```

The `list` class has a `.append()` method, and you do not need to import that method to be able to call it. All you need is a reference to a list instance.

<sub><sup>Technically speaking, a python `list` is a *type*, but that distinction does not matter here. On the whole, types are the same things as classes, for the purpose of this discussion.</sup></sub>

Please do go and read the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), it explains classes in a later chapter (but you may want to skim through the first set of chapters first).

Comment: Your answer came off as if I were more ignorant than I am. The problem is not of "object oriented", I know what an instance of a class is.... I am from the C++ world. The question is from "dynamic vs static typed". In C++, in y.py, you would have to include a header that gives the signature of objOfTypeX.functionThatReturnsAString(), or else at compile time it would say "objOfTypeX has no method named ...". In python I guess it looks for this method to exist at runtime, and otherwise, throws an error. Your answer did not touch on this, so I am accepting another.

Comment: That is, I was unsure why funct() does not need to be informed that the method functionThatReturnsAString() actually exists, as you must "prove" in C++ by telling y.py that this function does indeed exist. I did not know that python does not require such proof, and just bombs at runtime saying "this function doesn't exist like you said it did".

Comment: @Tommy: In all fairness, that was *not* apparent from your question *at all*. Some indication *how you expected* things to work would have been helpful to make that clearer.

Comment: @Tommy: And also to be clear: Glad you found an answer that helped you! That's what SO is all about, and kudos to Josh Heitzman to have realized what your problem was. :-)

Comment: My comments "#NO IMPORT STATEMENT NEEDED?? WHY" and "from x import functionThatReturnAString()" was meant to signal I was confused as to why I do not need to inform y.py about the existence of this function as in other OO langs like C++/Java.

Comment: @Tommy: But that could only be guessed by someone else with enough experience in Java and/or C++ *and* familiar with the possibility of confusion there.

Answer (score 1):

Function `yTypeObj.func` is called from `main.py` where the class is imported. Therefore the object may be constructed and passed to the function, with all of its methods (`functionThatReturnAString` is a method of `objOfTypeX`).

Comment: so I don't really understand when imports are needed then. Not in any class that calls a method of another class, because y calls a function of x.

Comment: You need to import the class (or any other attribute) when you want to define a new object. Otherwise, you would not have a recipe to construct an new object. You may pass the object to any function you like (which does not have to be aware of existance of such a class)